# Disable input fields if a variable is not set

Tags: php, html, css

I have a webpage which allows user to upload an image ONLY IF he is logged in , I'm using session_start() to get my variable $_SESSION['username']. How can I set my text image field such that its only enabled/visible when there is a set value for $_SESSION['username'].

My code below:

```
 <form action="uploadtofile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- data">
<input  id="bc0" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" >
<input  id="bc1" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" >
</form>
session_start();
if(isset{$_SESSION['username']{
```

.bc01.visibility="hidden}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code below, the `form` will only display if the user is logged in.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo'
<form action="uploadtofile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="bc0" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input id="bc1" type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
';
}
?>
```

Comment: thankyou the answer works like a charm, the fields are hidden if the user isnt logged in !

Comment: @AbsarA.Khan _No problemo! :)_

Comment: one more question if u dont mind :)
i want to echo the username (that was passed via my session variable and echo "hello (username) " if im logged in or say " hello guest " if im not logged in. can u tell me what im doing wrong please 
' <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
          echo "WELCOME '.$_SESSION['username').' " ; 
         }
         else
          echo ' WELCOME GUEST';

         ?> '

Answer (score 0):

Good to see you've created a
`session_start();`
many people have issues remembering to do that!

You can then do as follow and create an if statement that is triggered when they're details are correct:

```
if(check the db details and compare to see if logged in)
{
    $_SESSION['logCheck'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
}
```

Then create a function, if you want to use it several times, to check if they're logged in:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logCheck']) && $_SESSION['logCheck'] == true) {
    echo "Logged in" . $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo "Not logged in";
}
```